# Creating multiple workbooks from a column or field

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

after I read my desired file in

```
df = pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat')
```

say i have a column or field in the table named:

```
[Peoples_Names]
```

and I want to make an excel doc for each idividual person in that column by name. is their a way to do that without manually going through and making a script for each one by hand that does that. I want the program to basically take in that column and kick out multiple excel workbooks for each individual by name.

Comment: You could use `df.groupby('Peoples_Names')` then loop through the groups and export out each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt based on what i think you are asking for. I grab a list of the values from a certain column, create a df filtering out all other people except one person, then create a file for each name with the name as the name of the person. Let me know if you need help or if this is not what you were asking for:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,0,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [0,0,1,3], 
                    'C' : ['Mary','Bob', 'Nancy','Chris'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly']})

names= list(df1['C'].values)

for person in names:
    df2= df1[df1['C'] == person]
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('YOUR PATH HERE' + str(person) + '.xlsx')
    df2.to_excel(writer, person)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @Cannon, my pleasure! What is important is that you see my progression (which i tried to outline). If you need help understanding I can try and walk you through it.

Comment: Yeah that would be great! If you get the time I would definitely be grateful so I can understand the progression.

Comment: @Cannon, Sure. You asked to make a process without creating something manually. My first thought was when you ever want to replace monotonous processes, you'll want to use a loop. To use a loop I needed a list of the people's names: `names` in my example. Then I thought, let's loop through the names and make a data frame for each one: `df2=df1['C'] == person]`. Now lets write that file, with a unique name, to where i need it to go. look at `writer` and notice the combination of the strings to make the persons name an excel file. Then lets use that string as the file path and send it!

Comment: Okay thats makes alot of sense I didnt figure that it would be this simple, but that is the power of looping. Thanks for the explanation and the help!

Comment: This is great. is there a way to have this loop over and just truncate and load a tab for each matching excel file and its contents

Comment: @Tinkinc, I'm confused on what you mean. If you have another question that is not a duplicate of another post, feel free to post a new question! answering more than one question in the comments is frowned upon here